# iOS - a questions about present and push the controllers

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

There are five `controllers here, AViewController, BViewController, CViewController,DViewController,EViewController,`controllers here,

```
A present---> B
B present---> C
C push--->D
D push--->E
```

Now, if I want to go back from EViewController to AViewController in one step, what code should I write?

Comment: from EViewController to AViewController in one step。if i use your way ,it just back to DViewController.not A

Comment: Use blocks, until dismiss EViewController to BViewController. Call a block after popToRootViewControllerAnimated method, it will take you on CViewController, than use dismiss block.

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:animated];
```

Comment: do you have any other solutions?because i have another rootViewController

Answer (score 1):

1) Getting the desirable ViewController as Below

```
for (id controller in [self.navigationController viewControllers])
   {
   if ([controller isKindOfClass:[AViewController class]])
  {
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
    break;
  }
  }
```

2) Here you have A,B,C,D,E Controllers. means A would be on 1 Position so what can you do

you can hard wired the Index as Below

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

3) Pop to the first viewController or rootViewController

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:animated];
```

Comment: It doesn't work.the way A to B and B to C is present,not push....C to D,D to E is push.

Answer (score 0):

Use unwind segues. 
In AViewController add bellow code

```
-(IBAction)prepareForUnwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
}
```

Go to User Interface of EViewController and Ctrl-drag from the button (you want set action) to the “Exit” outlet, you will see a modal popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it recursively with generic solution. First of all you should have reference to A's navigation controller and then you should write recursive method to get active navigation controller like :`

```
-(UINavigationController*)getActiveNavigationController : (UINavigationController*)navigationController {    

if ([navigationController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[AViewController class]]) {

    return [self getActiveNavigationController:(UINavigationController*)((AViewController*)navigationController.presentedViewController)
            ];

}

if ((UINavigationController*)navigationController.presentedViewController == nil) {

    return navigationController;

}

return [self getActiveNavigationController:(UINavigationController*)navigationController.presentedViewController];

}
```

`

After that you should write method like

```
-(void)getInitialScreen:(UINavigationController*)AViewControllerNavigationController {

if ([AViewControllerNavigationController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[AViewController class]]) {

    return;

}
 UINavigationController *navigation = [self getActiveNavigationController:AViewControllerNavigationController];
 [navigation dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self getInitialScreen:AViewControllerNavigationController];
}];

}
```

finally after you wrote those 2 methods. You can call them like below and you can always get AViewController

`[self getInitialScreen:AViewControlelrnavigationcontroller];
 [AViewControlelrnavigationcontroller popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`